# StackOverflow shop?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, shop

Are SO Team planning some SO stuff shop?

---

**Stack Exchange Store** - As of 2 July 2012, the [shop is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store).

<strike>http://shop.stackexchange.com/</strike>

---

**What stuff SO users want?**

Mugs, Stickers, T-Shirts or Posters :)

[What kind of Stack Exchange & community swag do you want](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86498/what-kind-of-stack-exchange-community-swag-do-you-want)

---

**Stickers**

- [Trilogy Stickers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/coming-soon-trilogy-stickers/) - from SO team

Comment: I bet they could partner with ThinkGeek...

Comment: Note that as of 2011-06-01 19:05Z there seems to be a http://shop.stackexchange.com/

Comment: piskvor: please, add as answer

Comment: [status-the-shop-is-no-more]

Answer (score 16):

You should have a mug or a t-shirt that says

"Please stand back, I am trying to beat Jon Skeet's answer"

and on the T-Shirt have a ninja in some sort of fighting pose. (optional)

Answer (score 9):

Great idea!  I'd love a digital Stack Overflow doormat that displays my current flair!

Comment: I was more thinking along the lines of a "t-shirt with real-time flair printed on it" ;-)

Comment: I just told my wife two days ago that if DevDays ever came near Atlanta I would print my flair/picture on a shirt and wear it :)

Comment: Or making this a hybrid of a wifi detector shirt with automatic flair updater

Answer (score 4):

Note that [Brent Ozar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/26837/brent-ozar) already does [Stack Overflow T-shirts](http://shirt.social-shirt.com/stackoverflow-shirt.html).

Comment: oops... broken linky

Answer (score 4):

A mosaic of monochrome user-icons would be kinda cool. But it would need some witty phrase to complement it - any suggestions? :)

[Enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9usTv.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Haha that's kinda cool. It would be a pretty cool t-shirt on it's own, maybe with more people on it and maybe the text "Neither rain, nor snow, nor sleet, nor hail shall keep us from fixing your overflowed stacks!"

Comment: So just have all Icons from the +10k club and just label it: StackOverflow Class of 2009. Next years shirt can be the next group of 10k users.

Comment: @KP haha brilliant.

Comment: I don't think I could feature only the +10k group until I'm in the +10k group ;)

Answer (score 4):

A t-shirt idea (this isn't my creation):
[image: The StackOverflow League of Justice]

Comment: He he... Cool dude.. Cngrats @Jon Skeet for becoming Super Man... :)

Answer (score 2):

A Poster with the top 50 users with the title

"Followers of Jon Skeet"

And with him at the top like a king.

Comment: So what do I get to put on *my* T-shirt?

Comment: @Jon: I AM Jon Skeet :)

Comment: You should just get a "Yes, I am Jon Skeet" or "Will the real Jon Skeet please stand up" tshirt.

Comment: I was thinking of something slightly more cryptic: "22656. Yes, really." It's quite hard to think of things which are funny but don't make me look like an arrogant git though. (Or even more of an arrogant git, depending on your current impression of me.)

Comment: That's to cryptic for me :D

Comment: SELECT user_id FROM USERS ORDER BY reputation WHERE rownum <= 1;

Answer (score 1):

I'd settle for simple branded goods; pens/shirts/mugs with the stackoverflow logo. It's a very nice logo. :)

Answer (score 1):

A LED screen that displays your current Stack Overflow rep score in Orange, Server Fault rep in Red, Super User in Bright Blue, and maybe Meta in dim white?

Answer (score 0):

You should have T-Shirts with the flair of the user but with the ≈ or ~ approximation signs in front of the reputation.

Comment: I would assume that ~ meant bitwise negation.

Answer (score 0):

A T-Shirt or Mug that says

"I hit the soft cap before lunch!" (or rep cap)