# Help design our Stack Overflow t-shirts

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, t-shirt, merchandise

In the spirit of [How would you design a Stack Overflow T-Shirt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/how-would-you-design-a-stackoverflow-t-shirt), [Michael](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/245/michael-pryor) came up with these three mockups (in answers).

Please vote and comment, or — if you're feeling extra frisky — propose alternative designs using these handy dandy image templates:

- [T-Shirt template, front](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/5772/tshirttemplate.png)
- [T-Shirt template, back](http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/3650/tshirttemplateback.png)

Post your own designs in the answers, and we'll let the votes decide.

**edit (by Kyle)**: It seems that the SO shirts are [right around the corner](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/7691404224) - any last-minute ideas or designs?

Some new action:

http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/8947/stackoverflowtshirtsspy.jpg

Comment: I know that the white shirts are in tune with the SO design, but I would prefer a light gray for practical reasons (coffee stains...)

Comment: the white is an artifact of the template; some will come in white or black as specified in the line under the header.

Comment: Would be awesome if we can get the community's favorite badge. Or have a shirt for every badge.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me I should read the whole thing before posting  a comment...?

Comment: I like how the model for the "back" template seems to be a weight lifter.

Comment: @treb Tri-blend!

Comment: Aw, man... I just realized I'm going to miss all the t-shirt cannon fun at SO Dev Days.

Comment: How many colors is SO going to be permitting on these shirts?

Comment: There are some ideas here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/stackoverflow-shop

Comment: What these shirts need are a low power lcd segment display, a wifi interface, and a pic chip (or other embedded cpu) that grabs your flair json and shows relevant data on the segments. Like other shirts with displays, it'd be attached with velcro.

Comment: Any chance of polo shirts with just a small logo in addition to the other shirts?

Comment: any possibility to order a stack overflow shirt now? :/

Comment: Wait, where do we buy these? I totally want one...

Comment: Want shirt.  Want it now.

Comment: I answered 200 questions on stackoverflow.com and all I got was this lousy t-shirt !

Answer (score 129):

A late entry... the geek pride is in getting the reference.

(besides - I'd **love** to deliver this to one of the "your text banner" t-shirt printers and watch them go crazy trying to figure it out ;-p)

[image: He comes]

Comment: ...which made me realise that the bottom-part of that post looks different on my computer. Or did you change it a bit? (Might be related to http://superuser.com/questions/52671/how-do-i-create-unicode-smilies-like/58534#58534 which doesn't look like expected on my Mac either. Guess I need to view that post on a PC then!)

Comment: If only it could be.

Comment: That is how it appears in both Chrome and Paint on my Win7 (en-uk)

Comment: Ah, bobince's original post looks the same (as my Mac) in Firefox on some recent Ubuntu Desktop installation, but much worse in IE7 on an old WinXP machine. In Chrome on that WinXP it's really missing many characters. Odd. I need to revise my view of the world as I know it...

Comment: come on buddy...

Comment: what's the geeky about getting reference to the Yeats poem?
http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Second_Coming   Or is this used elsewhere as well?  sounds like something from blade runner, but Yeats was there first ;)

Comment: @dove - and did Yeats often use `<center>`? If so he was truly visionary.

Comment: @Marc Yeats was visionay but didn't use markup.  He did write "the centre cannot hold" in quoted poem above.  Coincendentally and orthogonally, I had lunch by his grave yesterday.

Comment: So where can I buy it?

Comment: @Zoredache - you want to buy *his grave* ?

Comment: @Marc, a late request: any chance you can post a screen capture of your browser's rendering of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 ? (Someone else posted *In all its glory: http://imgur.com/gOPS2.png* in that answer's comments, but that's still not as beautiful as your shirt!)

Comment: @Marc, just in case you're in to it, see [Displaying Unicode (Bobince's post) on Chrome vs Firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/232636/displaying-unicode-bobinces-post-on-chrome-vs-firefox).

Comment: I want it. Now. Please!

Comment: @dove. I've climbed Ben Bulbin, but I never got to visit Drumcliff Churchyard. I must do, next time I'm in that part of the country.

Answer (score 98):

Not to rip off Mr. Atwood, but I suggest: (in American Apparel Tri-Blend)
[image: Clothed]

Comment: The particulars of the spacing and sizing and radii and whatnot might be off. I'm a bit drunk. Also, I used helvetica because... HELLO? Arial?

Comment: Being clothed should indeed earn anyone a gold badge. Please let that be incentive enough!

Comment: This *IS* the internet :-P

Comment: Oh it is fortuitous that this thread has reactivated, and that I am drunk yet again. Oh frabjous day. Now, how to beat that bastard Konrad Rudolph with his recursive tshirt.....

Comment: PLEASE make this shirt. I will buy 50

Answer (score 77):

### Downvotes

White or black

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dislike shirts with logos on back. Very "trade show."

Comment: I *should* downvote this, just for the lulz.

Comment: This is the one. I'd buy this today.

Comment: This should be [on hold] now ;)

Answer (score 64):

### Simple

[image]

[image]

Comment: Idea: instead of having the bits tip over... have them stack all the way up OVER the shoulder so they run over the back

Comment: I second Christopher Swasey's idea. just text on the back looks ... boring, but accomodating the media t-shirt with it's own characteristics makes logo-shirts special.

Comment: I love the front of this design, but just putting text on the back needs to go.

Comment: Could one in fact rely on the printer to match the front and back, as to allow for running something from front to back?

Comment: I like this design but I would take the SO logo / name on the back and make it WAY smaller and move it to the right shoulder line. Many companies are doing this now because it puts their logo more in line of sight and keeps the logos small.

Comment: I really prefer this idea. Maybe in polo, with the logo on the pocket?

Answer (score 39):

### Deliberate

[image: status by design t-shirt]

Comment: Probably too meta.

Comment: also a bit small, would it even fit me? tiny!

Comment: Think of the new child process you've recently spawned.

Comment: I like this. It's not particularly geeky, so it would be fine for walking down the street. Muggles would just think status-bydesign was an obscure fashion label or something.

Comment: @Charlie Muggles? What IS this place? Muggle Overflow? :)

Comment: I love this one.

Answer (score 19):

Something as minimalist as StackOverflow design but with emphasis on what makes the site so addictive:

Front. StackOverflow logo with a representative count golden, silver, and bronze badges.

[alt text http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/5772/tshirttemplate.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/5772/tshirttemplate.png)

Back. Some representative badges.
[back http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/3650/tshirttemplateback.png](http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/3650/tshirttemplateback.png)

Mmmh I can't think were to put a "representative" reputation score.

Obviously these are the Jon Skeet numbers :P But since [SO is you](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/) and Jon Skeet is SO then we all are Jon Skeet... somehow.

Comment: Somehow I manage to drop the colors .. mmhhh... I gues I'm just using the "Unix" side of OSX and not the "designer" side.

Comment: +1 mostly for the "we all are Jon Skeet" bit. ;-)

Comment: I'd move Autobiographer around (or replace it with something shorter). It looks unbalanced.

Comment: I like the front although the badge numbers could either be the total amount of badges on the site or smaller icons of the other sites. Then you could have a set of other shirts which have the other sites as those logos and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Graphs shows SO verses experts-exchange traffic, taken from [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/us-versus-hyphen/).

Comment: Please remove the extra character between experts and exchange.

Answer (score 5):

"Read this line, and do what it says twice."

Idea stolen from:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/how-would-you-design-a-stackoverflow-t-shirt

Answer (score 4):

No graphic program here, so maybe I just post it (text only):

```
char buf[5];
strcpy(buf,"Hello");
```

could do a **.com** behind those two lines :).

Comment: A little bit geeky, isn't it? ;)

Comment: hm. I think it fits :). But obviously that just me :)

Comment: If that’s supposed to be a stack overflow, you failed. Although it overflows onto stack space, it’s still a buffer overflow. To be precise, it’s a stack buffer overflow: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow

Comment: you are right, but I think a stack buffer overflow is an error more dangerous and more common. Thus I choose that one. And just writing char buf[STACKSIZE+1]; is a bit lame :).

Comment: You could change it to:

int main(void) { flow(); return 0;}
void flow(void) { flow();}

The idea stays the same ...

Comment: Or even shorter, `int main(void) { return main(); }`.

Answer (score 4):

Not the best one, but this could be funny *:)*

[image]

Comment: Why the include?

Comment: Returning 0 from `main` is implicit...