# Using logo to make myself a t-shirt

Tags: support, logo, legal

I'm pondering making myself a [bobince-inspired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) SO t-shirt.

I'm pretty certain that "*Do not use the names or logos owned by Stack Overflow Inc. on any apparel or merchandise without our permission*" ([here](https://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance)) doesn't apply in this case, but can I have official permission?

Comment: The post does not have a logo. IMHO and IANAL If you attribute the source somewhere on the Tee, you could even sell those Tshirts with the post on them. Would love to hear other opinions.

Comment: What would the shirt look like? In what context would SO's name or logo be used?

Comment: Just the logo, with the central phrase of bobince's answer.

Comment: Before the powers that be at SO can answer, you should make a mock up of the proposed T shirt [see this link for an example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18382/help-design-our-stack-overflow-t-shirts/35432#35432)

Comment: @abel, well it's pretty much the same, but without the unicode, and just the logo, no name.

Answer (score 6):

We do not object to your individual use of the logo in a personal and private manner.

Like, say for using the logo on a tee shirt you plan to wear yourself.*

If I'd asked our lawyers**, they'd probably want me to say that we do not grant others permission to use our logo in commerce. (That means no selling them. No using the shirt to convince others that you are me. Or Joel. Or Sparkles the Unicorn.)

*I think it's okay if you lend it to immediate family members, too.

**I asked my dad, who used to be lawyer, what our lawyers would say.