# May I create a T-shirt with Stack Overflow logo?

Tags: support, legal, logo, shop

The possible duplicate of [Using logo to make myself a t-shirt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74835/using-logo-to-make-myself-a-t-shirt) is still unanswered.

I have read the [Trademarks Guideline](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), but I'm unable to figure out whether I as an individual am wearing T-Shirts

- because I don't wanna be naked
- for advertising reasons
- to merchandise myself

The OP's question was lacking the T-Shirt design, so here it is (notice the realism):

[image: T-Shirt design]

I also read [Anna's answer to "Can I use Stack Exchange logos on a t-shirt or other apparel?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157244/245641), but according to the definition of "merchandising" (Wikipedia, not sure if that counts)

> ... merchandising is any practice which contributes to the sale of products to a retail consumer.

I wonder whether this really applies to single T-shirts worn by myself.

Also note: [there used to be a shop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68841/stack-overflow-t-shirt-where-can-i-get-one-for-now) to buy T-shirts regularly. Just because this shop cannot deliver as many T-shirts as requested by SO users does not necessarily indicate that we can't create our own.

If T-shirts really aren't allowed, I'll go ahead and buy a Chuck Yeager helmet instead.

Comment: I think the answer is "no", but better wait for someone who can say it officially.

Comment: You can wear the printed t-shirt inside out in public, or wear when no one else is can see the logo on the t-shirt. ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We do not object to your individual use of the logo in a personal and private manner.

Like, say for using the logo on a tee shirt you plan to wear yourself.*

If I'd asked our lawyers**, they'd probably want me to say that we do not grant others permission to use our logo in commerce. (That means no selling them. No using the shirt to convince others that you are me. Or Joel. Or Sparkles the Unicorn.)

*I think it's okay if you lend it to immediate family members, too.

**I asked my dad, who used to be lawyer, what our lawyers would say.

Answer (score 7):

From Adam's comment on my answer to a question about the legitimacy (or otherwise) of a T-shirt being sold by someone else  ([Is this "University of stackoverflow" T-shirt legit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231915/is-this-university-of-stackoverflow-t-shirt-legit/231916#comment763485_231916))

> @DavidX.Random There's not much to add to what ChrisF already said. Unfortunately, this shirt isn't official in any way and, in fact, goes against our [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) - `Do not use the names or logos owned by Stack Exchange Inc. on any apparel or merchandise without our permission.`

So basically, unless you get permission from Stack Exchange, no you can't use the logo on a T-shirt even if it is only for your own personal use.

Comment: Note: I don't want to sell it. I'll also not add anything else like "University of", so this post doesn't really apply to my case.

Comment: @ThomasW. - I know you don't want to sell it, but Adam's statement doesn't make any mention of selling the apparel either.