# Can we print the SE logo by ourselves?

Tags: support, logo, merchandise

1. I've organised unofficial SOru event several month ago: [Неофициальная встреча в Москве 22 Марта в 19:00](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8861/15479). I've wanted to print SOru logo on T-shirts and give them to members, but CM told me that SO is against it.
2. We periodically receive questions on our meta about SE merchandise. (e.g. [Экипировка от SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9487/15479)).
3. Our 100k user still [hasn't received his prize from SE](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9487/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-so?cb=1#comment39290_9488) (almost a year passed).

People, at least, want to print SE logo by themself.

So:

1. Can members print the SE logo by themself?
2. If yes, could you provide high-resolution images?

Comment: Think the line is whether you sell those shirts for money or not. If selling, it's illegal. If just giving as swag prize, it might pass.

Comment: The question is if you printing the logo on your own T-Shirt that only you will wear is fair-use: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance

Comment: Deleted some comments. Let's not get into specifics of laws regarding trademark and copyright when we don't actually know how they work ourselves.

Comment: Related: [May I create a T-shirt with Stack Overflow logo?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244555/may-i-create-a-t-shirt-with-stack-overflow-logo)