# Jeff Atwood's top answers are shown incorrectly?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, voting

I was wondering how exactly [Jeff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) got over 100k of reputation on Meta.. so I took a look. His top answers(by votes) are the following:

[383 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010/33768#33768)

[123 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18382/help-design-our-stack-overflow-t-shirts/18385#18385)

However, if you look into these answers, you'll see something weird. The top answer is +71 and -18.. well that doesn't seem right.. and his second top answer is +9 and -1. Somehow that doesn't seem to add up to 123.

Is this a bug or has Jeff been dipping into the secret reserve of reputation? :)

Comment: Note that no one got any precious meta rep for any answer on either of those questions, as they were CW from the start... If you wanna track someone's rep, [try their rep page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=reputation)

Answer (score 7):

Notice the top answer says:

**`383` Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2010** (5)

That means he has **5 answers** for the same question.

You can see them all using the search: [[open-source-advertising] user:1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[open-source-advertising]+user%3A1)

Comment: it's still very misleading and the parenthesized value is not documented anywhere

Comment: @Earlz Hover over the vote numbers on Jeff's profile.

Comment: @Earlz: Yeah, it is confusing. On the other hand, answering the same question several times is not really something that should be happening often.