# Images in meta T-shirt questions seem to have become spam?

Tags: discussion

I was looking at the [boat programming meme explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about), which leads to [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18382/help-design-our-stack-overflow-t-shirts/18596#18596) about T-shirts, and then from there, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/how-would-you-design-a-stackoverflow-t-shirt). However, as you can see in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18383/227894) and in the latter question, it seems that some of the T-shirt images have become plugs for free iTunes gift cards (once you download a certain app)! It seems as if the images are hosted on imageshack.com, but I'm not sure if that's the problem. What do we do with these images?

<sub>Also, I have a secondary question, which is: what happened to the boat-programming answer in the "Help design our T-shirts" question? I can't find it, even though it's linked to from multiple boat-programming meme explanations...</sub>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising